# Oracle SQL Query - Between Two Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

For a report, i need to track movement of persons from one place to another within a given time range, based on their activities

Activities

| Name | TimeStamp | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 10-JAN-23 05:23:06 | Gym |
| Peter | 10-JAN-23 07:01:45 | Home |
| Peter | 10-JAN-23 08:09:26 | Restaurant |
| Peter | 10-JAN-23 09:19:32 | Office |
| Peter | 10-JAN-23 16:43:02 | Golf |
| John | 10-JAN-23 07:30:26 | Home |
| John | 10-JAN-23 08:30:43 | Gym |
| John | 10-JAN-23 10:02:06 | Theater |
| John | 10-JAN-23 12:00:32 | Soccer |
| John | 10-JAN-23 20:23:02 | Bar |

From the above table, let's say we need to track movement of people from 8AM to 8PM (08:00 to 20:00) the result would be as below.

| Name | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Home | Restaurant |
| Peter | Restaurant | Office |
| Peter | Office | Golf |
| John | Home | Gym |
| John | Gym | Theater |
| John | Theater | Soccer |

Using BETWEEN in WHERE CLAUSE the activity between the given range can be fetched. But I am unable to get the first 'FROM' place of each person as it falls outside the time range. I have tried with group by and window functions, but still unable to get the desired result. Can someone please help on this ?

| Name | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | ????? | Restaurant |
| Peter | Restaurant | Office |
| Peter | Office | Golf |
| John | ????? | Gym |
| John | Gym | Theater |
| John | Theater | Soccer |

Comment: For your current result you may use `coalesce(from_col, (select lkp.activity from table_name lkp where lkp.name = table_name.name and lkp.timestamp_col < table_name.timestamp_col order by timestamp_col desc fetch first row only))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LAG` analytic function in an inner-query and then filter on the time range in an outer query (if you do it the other way round then you will filter out the value before the start of the range before you can find it using `LAG`):

```sql
SELECT name,
       prev_activity AS "FROM",
       activity AS "TO"
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         LAG(activity) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timestamp) AS prev_activity
  FROM   activites a
)
WHERE  timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 08:00:00'
                     AND TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 20:00:00';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE activities ( Name, TimeStamp, Activity ) AS
SELECT 'Peter', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 05:23:06',    'Gym' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Peter', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 07:01:45',    'Home' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Peter', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 08:09:26',    'Restaurant' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Peter', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 09:19:32',    'Office' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Peter', TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 16:43:02',    'Golf' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 07:30:26',    'Home' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 08:30:43',    'Gym' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 10:02:06',    'Theater' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 12:00:32',    'Soccer' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  TIMESTAMP '2023-01-10 20:23:02',    'Bar' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | FROM | TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Home | Gym |
| John | Gym | Theater |
| John | Theater | Soccer |
| Peter | Home | Restaurant |
| Peter | Restaurant | Office |
| Peter | Office | Golf |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5b704/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use the windowing `LAG(activity)` or `LEAD(activity) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timestamp)` to show the previous (or next) location. That's your FROM (or TO, whichever you prefer). Done.

Comment: I think the timestamp should indicate the start time for a certain activity, and not necessarily a location. Thus, you should have a table ACTIVITIES with an activity_id number primary key, a table PERSONS with primary key person_id and in the schedule you should have the columns: person_id, activity_id and start_timestamp, all of which should be not null. In the ACTIVITIES table there should also be a row for "Unknown activity" so that all the possibilities are covered.